# Faster method to remove non-letter characters from a string

Tags: c#, string, performance

I want to remove all characters from a string, except Unicode letters.

I consider using this code:

```
public static string OnlyLetters(string text)
{
    return new string (text.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
}
```

But maybe `Regex` will be faster?

```
public static string OnlyLetters(string text)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("[^\p{L}]");
    return rgx.Replace(text, "");
}
```

Could you verify this code and suggest which one should I choose?

Comment: another option is `return string.Concat(text.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c));`

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Additionally, I don't think Windows Forms is relevant to what you're asking - while it's entirely feasible that you're using this within a WinForms app, it's not really a WinForms-oriented question.

Comment: Regex will be not faster; on my workstation (.Net 6) regex ~ 2 times slower (440 ms vs. 180 ms) for processing a string with 10_000_000 characters

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `string.Concat(text.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c));` will be much slower owing to allocating Linq's enumerators and the double-copy of the data caused by `ToArray()` and `new String`.

Comment: Why did someone voted down my question? It would be better if you supported the new user.

Comment: Re *"Could you verify this code"*: The *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)* site might or might not be better suited. Lurk and check their meta site first before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know which horse is faster, you can perform races:

Often, *manual* manipulations appear to be fast. Let's try this approach:

```
private static string ManualReplace(string value)
{
  // Let's allocate memory only once - value.Length characters
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  foreach (char c in value)
    if (char.IsLetter(c))
      sb.Append(c);

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Races:

```
// 123 - seed - in order for the text to be the same
Random random = new Random(123);

// Let's compile the regex
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string result = null; // <- makes the compiler happy

string text = string.Concat(Enumerable
                            .Range(1, 10_000_000)
                            .Select(_ => (char)random.Next(32, 128)));

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

// Warming: let .NET compile CIL, fill caches, allocate memory, etc.
int warming = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < warming; ++i)
{
  if (i == warming - 1)
    sw.Start();

  // result = new string(text.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());

  result = rgx.Replace(text, "");

  // result = string.Concat(text.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)));

  // result = ManualReplace(text);

  if (i == warming - 1)
    sw.Stop();
}

Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

Run this several times, and you'll get the results. Mine (.NET 6, Release) are:

```
new string    : 120 ms
rgx.Replace   : 350 ms
string.Concat : 150 ms
Manual        :  80 ms
```

So we have the winner. It's `Manual` replace; among the others `new string (text.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());` is the fastest, `string.Concat` is slightly slower, and `Regex.Replace` is a loser.

Comment: When I use a `StringBuilder` with a `for` loop it runs in `107ms`, while your winner "`new string(...`" runs in `130ms` - just sayin' (.NET 6 x64, v6.0.8, Release build)

Comment: @Dai: yes, `StringBuilder` - if we alllocate memory via `new StringBuilder(text.Length)` can well be even faster. Initially, I've performed races among the mentioned approaches only - `new string`, `Regex.Replace` and `String.Concat`.